# Evaluate "image" SQL column in a query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linqpad

I have a database containing a table with an "Image" colum:
[image: Management Studio Screncap]

This column actually contains a long string encoded as HEX byte values.

I need to select all records where the string encoded by this column contains a certain substring. Pseudocode would be:

```
Select *
From SomeTable
Where dataColumnofTypeImage.ToString().Contains("somesubstring")
```

I tried to do this in Linq (LinqPad) using:

```
from z in Zanus
let p = z.Udata.ToArray() // z.Udata will be of type System.Linq.Binary so I want to     make a byte array out of it...
where System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(p).Contains("EXED")
select new
{
    z.Idnr,
    z.Udatum,
    z.Uzeit,
    z.Unr,
    z.Uart,
    z.Ubediener,
    z.Uzugriff,
    z.Ugr,
    z.Uflags,
    z.Usize,
    z.Udata
}
```

But this does not work at all saying:

NotSupportedException: Method 'Byte[] ToArray()' has no supported translation to SQL.

I just cannot believe it would not be possible to check a binary datatype in a Where clause just as I might check some other datatype...

Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: What would you expect the ToString representation to look like anyway?  I would expect `System.Linq.Binary` or the character interpretation of the binary data, never the binary data itself, so even if it would compile your code would still be wrong.

Comment: Did you try PatIndex instead of Contains? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex.aspx

Comment: @Ed @shsmith The problem lies not with the string manipulation itself. I cannot seem to get the data out of the column in the first place. Please check my comments below for an example data, its human readable representation and the problem I have.

Comment: Have you thought about how would you write this in SQL? LINQ to SQL translates LINQ to SQL, so if there's no way to do this in SQL, you're snookered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of doing this is to use direct sql and the Substring

For example, something like :

```
string str1 = @"
    select 
        Idnr, 
        Udatum,
        Uzeit, 
        Unr, 
        Uart, 
        Ubediener, 
        Uzugriff, 
        Ugr,
        Uflags, 
        Usize, 
        Udata 
    from  Zanus 
    where Udata is not null 
       and SubString(Udata, 1 , 2147483647) like '%EXED%'" ;

    var query1 = this.ExecuteQuery<Zanus>(str1);
    (from z in query1 
    select new
    {
        z.Idnr,
        z.Udatum,
        z.Uzeit,
        z.Unr,
        z.Uart,
        z.Ubediener,
        z.Uzugriff,
        z.Ugr,
        z.Uflags,
        z.Usize,
        z.Udata
    }
```

Note, this will fail if the search string is in a column, but not in the first 2,147,483,647 bytes (but if these are images, I don't think that should be a concern).

Comment: Thanks for this... I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. The SQL query returned exctly those records which I was expecting and needed. There are some issues in making it run in Linq but that's syntax and a missing bracket or ; here and there. Really most helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
where p.Contains(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString("EXED"))
```

That would presumably be the code for what you're trying to do, whether it would work would depend on your image string

Comment: Doesnt work. An example: `code`0x3200001000000000000000200B00000012FF000003000000343000000000703000000033000000040000000000A841340000000400000000C07F4435000000040000000000A041FE010000040000009825E53B000000400E00000000FE000006000000454B47443600000000F000000000`code` which goves `code`?2?????????? ????????????40????p0???3??????????A4??????????D5??????????A?????????%?;???@????????????EKGD6?????????`code` where I am interested in the EKGD part. However, I get an error  `code`NotSupportedException: Method 'Byte[] ToArray()' has no supported translation to SQL.`code` It drives me nuts...