# Partial replace on SQL image data column

Tags: sql, encoding, replace, hex, substring

This question is related to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164937/evaluate-image-sql-column-in-a-query) I posted earlier.

To recap, I need to fix an issue with an ancient legacy app where people messed up data storage by re-installing the software the wrong way.

The application stores data by saving a record in an SQL DB. Each record holds a reference to a file on disk of which the filename auto-increments.

By re-installing the app the filename auto-increment was re-set so the DB now holds multiple unrelated records which reference the same filename and I have to directories with files which I obviously cannot merge because of these identical filenames. The files hold no reference to the DB data so the only course of action that remains is to filter the DB records on date created and try to rename "EXED" to "IXED" or something like that.

The DB is relatively simple with one table containing a column that holds data of type "Image".

An example content of this image data is as follows:

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

The data is apparently Hex which mostly encodes meaningless crap but also holds the name of physical files (towards the end of the data field) in the filesystem that is linked to the SQL records:

```
??@7???????????EXED48bb?-P??????Dyspnoe??P??????VELD RAMP 360
```

I'm interested in the EXED part.

There is no clear regularity in the offset at which the filename appears and the filename is of variable length (so I do not know beforehand how long the substring will be).

I can call up all records with SQL like this:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) as "Number of EXED Files after critical date"
    FROM [ZAN].[dbo].[zanu]
    WHERE udata is not null 
          and SUBSTRING(udata, 1 , 2147483647) like '%EXED%' 
          and [udatum] > 0 
          and CONVERT(date,[udatum]) > CONVERT(date,'20100629')
```

What I would like to do now is know how to replace this EXED substring by something else (e.g. IXID).

I'm unfamiliar with SQL and Googling so far has yielded very little information on my options here.

I also have no other info on the original code that generated this data/the data format/encoding/whatever...

It's a mess really.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: `IMAGE` is a binary column type, therefore you cannot use the string functions on it.... I guess you'll have to load the binary blob in your favorite front-end language and deal with it there....

Comment: I was afraid so. Any chance you could get me going? This sort of thing is not my strong point... I would be eternally grateful of course! :)

Comment: What would your favorite front-end language be? Basically, you need to select that `IMAGE` column, store it in an appropriate array of bytes or something, and then search that array to find and replace the string you're interested in .

Comment: C# or something C or java related... I'm looking into it now but this stuff is just so tedious :)

Comment: Hardly impossible, see below...

Answer (score 0):

An update on this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;

namespace ZANLinq
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                DataContext zanDB = new DataContext(@"Data Source=.\,1433;database=ZAN;Integrated Security=true");


                string strSQL = @"SELECT 
                                    Idnr, 
                                    Udatum, 
                                    Uzeit, 
                                    Unr, 
                                    Uart,
                                    Ubediener, 
                                    Uzugriff, 
                                    Ugr, 
                                    Uflags, 
                                    Usize, 
                                    Udata 
                                 FROM Zanu 
                                 WHERE (Udata IS NOT null and SubString(Udata, 1 , 2147483647) LIKE '%EXED%')
                                 AND (Idnr = '           2')";

                var zanQuery = zanDB.ExecuteQuery<Zanu>(strSQL);

                List<Zanu> list = zanQuery.ToList<Zanu>();

                foreach (Zanu zanTofix in list)
                {
                    string strOriginal = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(zanTofix.Udata);
                    string strFixed = strOriginal.Replace("EXED", "IXED");
                    zanTofix.Udata = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strFixed);
                }

                zanDB.SubmitChanges();

                //Console.WriteLine(zanResults.Count<Zanu>().ToString());

            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It finds the records I'm interested in, I can easily manipulate the data but **the commit doesnt work**. I'm stumped, there are no exceptions, no indication the code is wrong.

Anybody have ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I think the above does not work because my table appears to have a composite PK (I cannot change this):

[image: Columns]

Since I could not debug this (no info anywhere, no exceptions, just a silent fail of the submitchanges()) I decided to use another approach and abandon Linq2SQL altogether:

```
try
            {
                SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=.\,1433;database=ZAN;Integrated Security=SSPI");

                DataSet zanDataSet = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter zanDa;
                SqlCommandBuilder zanCmdBuilder;

                thisConnection.Open();      

                //Initialize the SqlDataAdapter object by specifying a Select command 
                //that retrieves data from the sample table.
                zanDa = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT 
                                              Idnr, 
                                              Udatum, 
                                              Uzeit, 
                                              Unr, 
                                              Uart,
                                              Ubediener, 
                                              Uzugriff, 
                                              Ugr, 
                                              Uflags, 
                                              Usize, 
                                              Udata 
                                           FROM Zanu 
                                           WHERE (Udata IS NOT null and SubString(Udata, 1 , 2147483647) LIKE '%IXED%')
                                           AND (Idnr = '           2')
                                           AND (Uzeit = '13:21')", thisConnection);

                //Initialize the SqlCommandBuilder object to automatically generate and initialize
                //the UpdateCommand, InsertCommand, and DeleteCommand properties of the SqlDataAdapter.
                zanCmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(zanDa);

                //Populate the DataSet by running the Fill method of the SqlDataAdapter.
                zanDa.Fill(zanDataSet, "Zanu");

                Console.WriteLine("Records that will be affected: " + zanDataSet.Tables["Zanu"].Rows.Count.ToString());

                foreach (DataRow record in zanDataSet.Tables["Zanu"].Rows)
                {
                    string strOriginal = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])record["Udata"]);
                    string strFixed = strOriginal.Replace("IXED", "EXED");
                    record["Udata"] = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strFixed);

                    //string strPostMod = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])record["Udata"]);  
                }

                zanDa.Update(zanDataSet, "Zanu"); 

                thisConnection.Close();

                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

This seems to work but any input on why the Linq does not work and whether or not my second solution is efficient/optimal or not is still very much appreciated.